# Get \ref for equations working like \cite for contiguous references

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

When referencing a list of equations like `see Eq.12, 13, 14 and 15` the `\cite` command behaviour, which allows a single list of references, should be preferred I think. Is there something equivalent for the `\ref` command that would allow `\ref{eq1,eq2,eq3}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\cref` macro of the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package is your friend.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:a}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:b}
d^2 + e^2 = f^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:c}
g^2 + h^2 = i^2
\end{equation}

See \cref{eq:a,eq:b,eq:c}.

\end{document}
```

[image]